# Any one can help finding a distribution function?

Tags: probability-distributions

I am looking for a distribution function with the following characteristics:

F_x(x) is Continuous, differentiable and truncated on some [a,b].
I also need that that the density around the lower bound will be of measure zero, meaning:  f_x(a)=0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [extreme value theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory) we have the [Frechét distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_distribution) that almost fulfills your requirements: It is continuous, differentiable and the density is zero at the left end-point. The distribution function is given by

$$ 
\Phi_\alpha(x) = e^{-x^{-\alpha}}, \quad x\geq 0
$$
for $\alpha>0$ with density
$$
\varphi_\alpha(x) = \frac {{x}^{-\alpha}\alpha\,{{\rm e}^{-{x}^{-\alpha}}}}{x}, \quad x>0
$$
for which $\varphi_\alpha(x) \to 0$ for $ x\to 0$.
If you want it to be upper bounded, you could truncate it but I suppose that would beat the purpose of the distribution.